# Spam protection for public GPG keys?

Tags: pgp, gnupg, spam, threat-mitigation

Public keys published to a server almost always contain emails. Is there any sort of protection against bot harvesters that will use that email for spam?

Comment: In order to query a pgp server for a key, you must know at least one of the emails or name contained in that key. Besides, there are reports of spammers using that to get emails otherwise not published.

Comment: I know it's necessary  to provide them, I just wonder is it save.

Comment: What do you mean by "safe"? There is no way to keep your email private when publishing it.

Comment: I'm thinking of any form of spam protection like for example javascript. I don't mind having my email published, I just don't like the idea of an easy harvest. pgp.mit.edu returns emails in plaintext for instance...

Comment: I modified my answer to accommodate for the comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd like to start with a quote of [the FAQ of the MIT pgp server](https://pgp.mit.edu/faq.html):

> Yes, there have been reports of spammers harvesting addresses from PGP keyservers. Unfortunately, there is not much that either we or you can do about this. Our best suggestion is you take advantage of any spam filtering technology offered by your ISP.

Other than that:

If you rather keep an email address as private as possible, you are free to exchange your PGP key for that address using the same safe channel that you transmit the address itself.

So, if you do not upload the key, you can still distribute it privately and use it, without running into spam problems from that harvesting vector at least.

And to follow up with the comments on the question:

In order to be able to programmatically process the data (e.g. search for the email, the name, make sure it gets sent right) there has to be specified how to access the data. This specification can then be followed by the spammers too.

You could use obfuscation that cannot be computationally easy deobfuscated. But then, your email program would no longer be able to match keys with email addresses when sending messages - or require much more user effort on the key management - which really seems to much effort for most users like it is now.

Comment: Thank you for tweaking the answer according to discussion in comments. Speaking of obfuscation: is it common practice to, let's say, put an string like mdrgNOSPAM(at)gmail.com instead of mdrg@gmail.com (not an valid email BTW)? And does it really help? Because I sense from your answer that the possible gain is simply not worth the effort.

Comment: That'd probably not help. You could use a comment in the local part of the published address and apply filter rules to those mails containing the comment. (See the rfc for comments in email addresses)